# how to install english edition software with apt-get?

Tags: apt, locale

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, and locale is `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`. When I use `apt-get` to install software, it automatically install Chinese edition for me.

How can I make it to install English edition for me?

Answer (score 3):

Change the LANGUAGE variable temporarily for that command:

```
LANGUAGE=en sudo apt-get install xyz
```

Comment: If `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` didn't work use `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`. This what works for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson , use `LANGUAGE`, I figure out that there is no need to specify `LANGUAGE` when install, just specify `LANGUAGE` when open software, it uses english edition.

Comment: Thanks both for the correction; I edited the answer accordingly. Just a remark, @Sneetsher: LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 is actually not correct. The LANGUAGE variable shall contain a list of language codes without the .UTF-8 part. The reason why it seemed to work is that you removed the previous value, and since the new value was wrong it fell back to English.

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger generation manually, do:

```
sudo locale -gen
```

You may also generate new locales by run this following commands:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```